# Confusion about threads in Project Reactor's flatMap

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm playing around with Project Reactor and reactive MongoDB repositories. I have a following code:

```
@Builder
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Document
public class Person {
    @Id
    Integer id;
    String name;
}
```

```
public interface ReactivePersonRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Person, Integer> {
}
```

and main `@SpringBootApplication` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ReactiveDatabaseApplication {

    private final ReactivePersonRepository reactivePersonRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReactiveDatabaseApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        Scheduler single = Schedulers.newSingle("single-scheduler");
        IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i ->
                Flux.just(Person.builder()
                        .id(i)
                        .name("PersonName")
                        .build())
                        .flatMap(personToSave -> {
                            System.out.println(String.format(
                                    "Saving person from thread %s", Thread.currentThread().getName()));
                            return reactivePersonRepository.save(personToSave);
                        })
                        //.publishOn(single)
                        .flatMap(savedPerson -> {
                            System.out.println(String.format(
                                    "Finding person from thread %s", Thread.currentThread().getName()));
                            return reactivePersonRepository.findById(savedPerson.getId());
                        })
                        //.publishOn(single)
                        .flatMap(foundPerson -> {
                            System.out.println(String.format(
                                    "Deleting person from thread %s", Thread.currentThread().getName()));
                            return reactivePersonRepository.deleteById(foundPerson.getId());
                        })
                        //.publishOn(single)
                        .subscribeOn(single)
                        .subscribe(aVoid -> System.out.println(String.format(
                                "Subscription from thread %s", Thread.currentThread().getName()))));
    }
}
```

The `Flux::subscribeOn` method description says that:

> As such, placing this operator anywhere in the chain will also impact
>   the execution      * context of onNext/onError/onComplete signals from
>   the beginning of the chain up to   * the next occurrence of a {@link
>   publishOn(Scheduler) publishOn}

which is a little bit confusing to me, because when I don't have any `publishOn` specified in processing chain, the printed values of threads' names are:

> Saving person from thread single-scheduler-1 - as expected
>
> Finding person from thread Thread-13
>
> Finding person from thread Thread-6
>
> Finding person from thread Thread-15
>
> Deleting person from thread Thread-6
>
> Deleting person from thread Thread-5
>
> Deleting person from thread Thread-4

which I don't understand why. Shouldn't the scheduler specified in `subscribeOn` method be used for each `flatMap` execution?

When I uncomment `publishOn` lines, everything is executed by given single scheduler, which is as expected.

Could anyone explain why the single scheduler isn't used by `flatMap` operations, when there are no `publishOn`?

Comment: Inside flatMap you susbcribe to a new Mono, provided by Reactive Mongo repository, which might publish data on a different thread than the one it was subscribed on. On the other hand publishOn enforces that on which thread the data is sent downstream. That's why it works as 'expected' in that case.
What is the reason you want to switch between threads? Unless you do some blocking thing, you don't really need to worry about this at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This contrived example may make it clearer:

```
Scheduler single = Schedulers.newSingle("single-scheduler");
Flux.just("Bob")
        .flatMap(x -> {
            System.out.println(String.format(
                    "Saving person from thread %s", Thread.currentThread().getName()));
            return Mono.just(x).publishOn(Schedulers.elastic());
        })
        .flatMap(x -> {
            System.out.println(String.format(
                    "Finding person from thread %s", Thread.currentThread().getName()));
            return Mono.just(x).publishOn(Schedulers.elastic());
        })
        .flatMap(x -> {
            System.out.println(String.format(
                    "Deleting person from thread %s", Thread.currentThread().getName()));
            return Mono.just(x).publishOn(Schedulers.elastic());
        })
        .subscribeOn(single)
        .subscribe(aVoid -> System.out.println(String.format(
        "Subscription from thread %s", Thread.currentThread().getName())));
```

Which will give something similar to:

```
Saving person from thread single-scheduler-1
Finding person from thread elastic-2
Deleting person from thread elastic-3
Subscription from thread elastic-4
```

Or, in other words, your reactive repository isn't publishing on the same scheduler, and *this* is why you see the behaviour you do. "Up until the next occurrence of `publishOn()`" doesn't mean the next time *your* code calls `publishOn()` - it can also be in any of the publishers in any of your `flatMap()` calls, which you will have no control over.